# why does ubuntu not recognise hard drive on windows 7

Tags: windows

Im trying to install ubuntu on window 7 virtual PC, when I boot to the ubuntu ISO image just before the partitioning stage where ubuntu confirms you have at leaset 4GB hard drive space the installer puts a cross on requirement indicating system does not have required amount of space...

however I have a 220GB hard drive with 20GB used to create the virtual disk..Its all a bit weird as I can't seem figure it out

Comment: Probably the disk hasn't been allocated any space and ubuntu doesn't understand Virtual PC formats. Try using `VMware Player` or `Virtualbox`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the dmesg output:
ata_piix 0000:00:07.01: >version 2.13
ata_piix 0000:00:07.01: >Hyper-V Virtual Machine detected, ATA device ignore set

Kernel was already patched ... but I guess we need a new Ubuntu release for it to work.
https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/1473491/

Comment: FYI: Don't try upgrading our 12.04.1 to 12.10 if you are running in Virtual PC. The kernel used after the upgrade still doesn't have the fix, so you system will not boot.

Comment: You can also hit in the installer F6 and add "ata_piix.prefer_ms_hyperv=0" as described here: http://unquietwiki.blogspot.com/2012/08/installing-ubuntu-1204-on-hyper-v.html

Comment: But I should add that I have so far been unable to install a stable Ubuntu in Virtual PC. It either corrupts the HDD image, randomly segfaults or corrupts the malloc heap, or spontaneously quits Virtual PC while booting the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't touched Virtual PC for ages, but here are my 2 cents (based on VirtualBox, should be similar):

When creating a new virutal machine you create a new virtual HDD, normally I would specify it as dynamically allocated instead of fixed size. So check your Virtual PC VM's settings and make sure you have a virtual HDD meets the minimum requirement. Also during the install process, make sure you choose the right virtual HDD.