# Ubuntu server version 12.04.2

Tags: 12.04, server

I am having trouble installing the 32 bit version of Ubuntu server 12.04.2 on my 32 bit Microsoft Virtual PC player? I get to the point of installation where it says I have no disk drive  detected and gives me an assortment of options to choose from to download drivers? I have no clue how to find the necessary driver. The pc I am using is a Dell Inspiron N4110 with an Intel i3 processor. Please help!!!

Comment: Try using Oracle VirtualBox.

Comment: I probably will because I am working on an assignment for school so I need a solid vm player that will operate Ubuntu desktop and server simultaneously.

Comment: Please read [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/235799/28369) and the comments. It might contain tips to make your setup work.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options as I see it:

1. Download [Oracle VirtualBox from here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).  This is what I use and I love it.  It has a lot of nice features like Snapshots, for example.  It is very stable, gets regular updates, and you can copy virtual disk files to other systems if you want and run them there.  It also has support for most virtual file systems so you can open VMs made by VMWare Player.  I recommend this if you are using these for personal use (or school), but probably not for enterprise.
2. Download [VMWare Player from here](https://www.vmware.com/download/player/download.html).  If you will be doing a lot VM management/hacking or if you are in an enterprise environment, you may want to start here and then upgrade to fancier VMWare offerings later.  VMWare has cool options like VMWare View Client where you can drive a VM that is running on a server from any thin client (like a laptop or even Android phone).  I have used this a lot and it is solid, albeit when a brand new kernel comes out sometimes you'll find yourself patching the make file, which isn't fun when you don't know what you're doing :-O
3. Keep fighting Virtual PC, until choosing to go with either option 1 or 2 above.  Hopefully your head has not exploded with frustration by the time you get there.

Comment: Thanks I see, I will have to change my vm player asap...every open source OS I have installed under virtual pc has worked Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Debian, guess its time to change lol...Appreciate the advice and will take into consideration.